# How to make a manual coloring in ILNumerics?

Tags: colors, visualization, ilnumerics, colorbar, color-mapping

I make some boxes with ILNumerics (right side of the picture). This boxes have different properties for each of them, as you can see at the left side.

[image]

Actually, I want to coloring the boxes as I defined. The color itself depend on the "Delta Rho", which has max value = 1 and min value = -1. I also want to show the color bar. How to make it happen? Anyone have a clue?

Btw, this is my code:

```
private void createBlockBody(BlockBody BlockBody, ILScene scene, ILPlotCube plotCube)
    {
        ILArray<double> A = ILMath.rand(1, 20) * 4 + ILMath.vec(1, 20);
        plotCube.Add(new ILTriangles("tri")
        {
            Positions = new float[,] { 
            // front side
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},

            //back side
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},

            //up
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z  + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z  + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},

            //up
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z  + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z  + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},

            //right
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X + (float) BlockBody.dx, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},


            //left
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z}, 

            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X,(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz}, 
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z},
            {(float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.X, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Y + (float) BlockBody.dy, (float) BlockBody.UpperLeftPoint.Z + (float) BlockBody.dz},
            },

            Colors = new float[,] { 
            // front side
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},

            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},

            //
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},

            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},

            //
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},

            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
            {(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},{(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho,(float) BlockBody.Rho},
        },
        });

        // configure the limits of the plot cube content (similar to zooming)
        plotCube.Limits.Set(
          new Vector3(0, 0, 1000),   // set the minimum X,Y,Z coordinate
          new Vector3(1000, 1000, 0));// set the maximum X,Y,Z coordinate

        // disable clipping at the plot cube edges
        plotCube.Plots.Clipping = null;
        SliceilPanel.Scene = scene;
        SliceilPanel.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer!

```
plotCube.Add(box);
var colormap = new ILColormap(Colormaps.Jet);
Vector4 key1 = colormap.Map((float)BlockBody.Rho, new Tuple<float, float>(-1, 1));
var test = key1.ToColor();
box.Color = test;
```